# Why is my URL encoding not working?

Tags: python, twitter, html-encode

Encoding some programmatic urls for Twitter, but for some reason my urls are giving me 500 errors.

Can anyone notice anything wrong with this? I'm trying to see if there's anything I'm not noticing or generating this error.

Here's the code:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=" + urlinfo + "&rpp=1&page=1")
```

And here's the eventual output:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel%2BOR%2Bi+feel%2BOR%2Bim+feeling%2BOR%2Bi%27m+feeling%2BOR%2Bi+am+feeling%2BOR%2Bi+dont+feel%2BOR%2Bi%27m%2BOR%2Bi+am%2BOR%2Bim%2BOR%2Bmakes+me%2BOR%2Bmakes+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmade+me%2BOR%2Bmade+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmaking+me%2BOR%2Bmaking+me+feel%2BOR%2Bmy+mood%2BOR%2Bi%27m+so%2BOR%2Bim+so%2BOR%2Bi+don%27t+feel&rpp=1&page=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I get a twitter 131 response which according to the docs should be treated as a HTTP 500 response.

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but have you considered that:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=feel+OR+make
```

Will cover the vast majority of all your OR'ing anyway?